# web ble connectivity with gatt_sensordata_app 2.0 firmware

Tags: movesense

I'm trying to interact with the gatt_sensordata_app firmware using the provided web ble and python client samples. Can anyone confirm that it is working with uptodate browsers and also using the >2.0 firmwares?

I'm using chrome 98.0.4758.109 on OSX 11.6.3. Also tried google chrome on Android without success.

I have been relying on working javascript code since a while for the default ble_std_services_ecgrr firmware ( 1.9 ). Only recently started working with gatt_sensordata_app and 2.0 firmwares in general.
I also tried to debug the failing gatt_sensordata_app index.html service lookup using parts of that "proven" code without success. Additionaly the newly installed default std_services_ecgrr firmware using 2.1.2 doesn't work anymore via web ble.

I uploaded Movesense-gatt_sensordata_app_w_bootloader.zip onto one device, Movesense-ble_std_services_ecgrr_module_w_bootloader.zip onto another and will try to verify my claims that the web ble ble_std_services_ecgrr 1.9 interaction works as soon as I can get hold of my third device.

Behaviour:

samples/gatt_sensordata_app/web_client/index.html after connecting:

Label: Device Movesense XY selected.
Table: Connection Status: false

No js output in console at all.

Further JS console debug:
Verified selectedDevice['Movesense XY'].gatt.connected == true after clicking "select device"

selectedDevice['Movesense XY'].gatt.getPrimaryService('34802252-7185-4d5d-b431-630e7050e8f0').then(service => {console.log('service', service)}).catch(error => {console.log('error', error)});

The promise never resolves, nor catches that error. For me it looks like it somehow remains stuck in gatt.getPrimaryService / gatt.getPrimaryServices call.

I also tried the provided python client gatt_sensordata_app/python_client/movesense_sensor_data.py on a raspberry pi ( Linux 5.10.17-v7l+ armv7l ) but without success:
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
Task was destroyed but it is pending!

I also tried connecting to both movesense firmwares via nrf connect and that seems to work but I can't interact with gatt_sensordata_app

Comment: I can confirm that interacting via web ble using default 1.9.4 firmware works. The newer firmwares used in the tests described in the question were both 2.1.2

Comment: Correction concerning nrf connect: I can access both apps and also interact with the gatt_sensordata_app firware 34802252-7185-4d5d-b431-630e7050e8f0 service. Also the showcase app works flawless. So the problem is really only with web ble in combination with firmwares > 2.0. Can't say for sure if gatt_sensordata_app 1.9.4 would work as I can't upload that firmware anymore.

Comment: It seems to be a known issue https://bitbucket.org/movesense/movesense-device-lib/issues/93/gatt_sensordata_app-not-working-with not exactly the behaviour I'm seeing but definitely related

Comment: This issue was fixed in Movesense firmware release 2.1.4.